# TFDV generate_stats_from_csv trigger an out of memory error

Tags: tensorflow-data-validation

i have a problem when generating stats over a small dataset (~10MB).

it takes to much time and consume to much memory (it reaches 25 GB of my memory which makes no sense ). and at the end it stops throwing an out of memory error.

Comment: If your csv data fits in memory(which will in your case), please try generate_statistics_from_dataframe method and set n_jobs=-1 to use all the cores in your machine.

Comment: yes i did that and it works. still i want to know why it did not generate stats from csv.